# Dual boot of windows 8.1 and ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, gparted

I run windows 8.1 and I feel like having a dual boot. Every time I start installing ubuntu, my system does not recognise windows. My partition table is GPT. What should i do to use ubuntu and windows as well in my pc?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the .iso image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Burn the .iso image using unetbootin
3. In the bios setup set priority to where you burned the image (example usb or dvd)
4. Check the choice 'Install Ubuntu'
5. Follow the instructions given.

Note:You should be careful with partitioning.You don't want to mess these things up.

Comment: But the did not work at all. While installing ubuntu an option saying "install ubuntu alongside windows 8" but that option is not coming which means ubuntu is unable to detect windows. I want to dual boot. tell me what should I do?

Comment: Did you follow the above steps?Also i have a hard time understanding you.Please correct any mistakes.

Comment: Also what do you mean by your system does not recognize windows?Can you boot into windows?

Comment: Yes I can boot into windows. After I install ubuntu, a screen appears saying to install ubuntu alongside windows. but at that point I am getting to erase the hard disk and install ubuntu only. That is my problem. How to get " install ubuntu alongside windows 8"